# Tensorflow and python numpy: how to concat tensor/list with specific index

Tags: python, list, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning

I was the author of [Tensorflow: how to concat tensor with specific index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57451767/tensorflow-how-to-concat-tensor-with-specific-index)

Today I want to concatenation this two list

```
tensor_a = [[[[255,255,255]]], [[[100,100,100]]]]
tensor_b = [[[[0.1,0.2]]], [[[0.3,0.4]]]]
```

into the format like this

```
tensor_d = [[[[[255,255,255],[0.1,0.2]]]], [[[[100,100,100], [0.3,0.4]]]]]
```

I need to do this convertion:

1. using tensorflow (so tensor_a  and tensor_b are tensors)
2. using list/numpy (so tensor_a  and tensor_b are lists)

How can I do?

Comment: You cannot do that concatenation with TensorFlow or NumPy because the size of the last dimension in each tensor is different (3 in the first one, 2 in the second one). That is, the resulting tensor would not have a well-defined shape. You would either have to pad the second tensor so sizes match, or use something like a [ragged tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensors), which may not be very convenient.

Comment: But I can concatenation tensor_a and tensor_b into [[[[255,255,255,0.1,0.2]]], [[[100,100,100, 0.3,0.4]]]] using np.concatenate, and the result of last dim = 5. But I don't know how to make the demand above come true.

Comment: You can do that concatenation because you are concatenating along the only axis that have different sizes. When you concatenate two tensors, every axis other than the concatenated one must have the same size. `tensor_a` here has shape `(2, 1, 1, 3)`, and `tensor_b` has shape `(2, 1, 1, 2)`. If you concatenate along the fourth axis you get shape `(2, 1, 1, 5)`. But what shape would concatenating along the third axis (which is what you want) get you? It would be `(2, 1, 2, ?)`, where `?` means that is `3` for one part of the tensor and `2` for another part, which is not possible.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answering.